# custom module date formatter for publication date

Tags: datetime

I have a Drupal 8 contrib module [AP Style Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_ap_style) that provides a formatter for dates to conform to the AP Style Guide date rules. When using the module [Publication Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/publication_date), this formatter does not come up as an option. The AP Style Date does come up in views and in managing field display for other date types. Is there a modification that needs to be made to the AP Style Date module or something in the publication date that needs to be modified?

Comment: AP Style Date provides a field formatter, which effects how a field (E.g. something that takes user input when creating the content) is displayed. "Publication date" on the other hand provides a display field that outputs a value set in the backend. So it does not expose itself to field formatters for rendering. So in other words, unfortunately they are not compatible. At least as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Publication Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/publication_date) module provides a function to define which formatters can be used. I added a patch, which we maintain locally, to add the defined "timestamp_ap_style" format to the options. Optionally, I could have added it inside a custom module, but the patch seemed to make more sense.

```
 function publication_date_field_formatter_info_alter(array &$info) {
   $info['timestamp']['field_types'][] = 'published_at';
   $info['timestamp_ago']['field_types'][] = 'published_at';
   $info['timestamp_ap_style']['field_types'][] = 'published_at';
 }
```

Update:
Recently I came across a [commit](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/smart_date/commit/3a77386) in the [Smart Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_date) with the same need that I had in the AP Style Date module. So, I tried that and it works.

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'timestamp' formatter as time ago.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "timestamp_ap_style",
 *   label = @Translation("AP Style"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "datetime",
 *     "timestamp",
 *     "created",
 *     "changed",
 *     "published_at",
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

Simple and elegant.